# Handle json in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

I am writing a function in node js which accepts 2 parameter - "param1" is "jsonObj" & "param2" is "xpath"(as String) but when I am trying to extract the value using jsonObj.xpath I am getting result as undefined as it is looking for xpath as a key in the json object rather than cDel.dInfo.env. Can someone please let me know how to extract the value of cDel.dInfo.env from jsonObj.

Below is the sample code -

```
const json = '{ "cDel": { "dInfo": { "env": "ACCEPTANCE", "ref": 103163 } } }';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

var getValue = (jsonObj,xpath) => {
       return jsonObj.xpath;
}

console.log(getValue(obj,"cDel.dInfo.env"));
```

Output is undefined.
Expected Output is ACCEPTANCE.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. Every property from `xpath` must be read separately. Something like:

```js
const obj = JSON.parse('{ "cDel": { "dInfo": { "env": "ACCEPTANCE", "ref": 103163 } } }');
const getValue = (jsonObj, xpath) => {
  const path = xpath.split(".");
  let value = jsonObj;
  
  while (path.length) {
    value = value[path.shift()];
  }
  return value;
}

console.log(`obj.cDel.dInfo.env => ${getValue(obj, "cDel.dInfo.env")}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Above code will work fine for json with no array. Since I want write generic function I think lodash suites my requirement.

Comment: Your question did not mention an array within the json

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lodash's [`get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

```js
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
 
_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3
 
_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

Comment: I would also recommend lodash rather than reinventing the wheel if you aren't already using it.

Comment: If you only want `get` from Lodash, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get

Comment: Thanks for the response. Lodash worked fine for me.